# Indentation issue in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, indentation, auto-indent

Like many others, I like writing my codes on several lines and I appreciate the auto-indent feature offered by RStudio. The issue suddenly started when the word `undefined` showed up in the code editor whenever I pressed `Enter` as I expected an automatic indentation. It is important to mention that this does not affect the proper running of the code.

```
my_fun <- function(xxx){
undefined   
}
```

NB: Actually, when I copied and pasted the code here, `undefined` was not copied to! I had to manually add it. Here is another example.

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>% 
undefinedhead()
```

Comment: If you go the to tool>global options>code, se the tab width for  insert spaces for tab and that will likely go away. It is just asking you to SET a tab preference

Comment: @sconfluentus Why don't you write this as an answer? It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is just RStudio telling you that you have not preset your tab spaces, but it is not actually dropping commands into your code.

You have the option of setting tabs to however many spaces you feel is appropriate and it allows teams to work with consistent spacing.

If you go to the main menu and click on `Tools > Global Options` and on the second tab in the left column click on`Code` . There you can set the spaces to meet your personal needs (or teams profile) and the `undefined` message will disappear.

This photgraph shows where you can find the preferences.

[image: This is what it should look like]